# NullPointerException on getSupportActionBar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am trying of show a collapsing_toolbar_layout using androidx and I got a
nullPointerException. The method getSupportActionBar() return null

this is my code:

```
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //here the problem.
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    collapsing_toolbar_layout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
    collapsing_toolbar_layout.setTitle("Title");
```

in my style:

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

and this is my toolbar:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    style="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"
    >
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBanderaMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bandera_panama"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        >

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This should be work even with a NoActionBar in my style, because I am
creating my own Toolbar and initializing it. However i still get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.alcampos.notificame, PID: 9455
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alcampos.notificame/com.alcampos.notificame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've extended your activity with AppCompatActivity.

Then simply use below code :

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

and in your `onCreate()`

```
 final Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

More information on Collapsing toolbar execution could be found [here](https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example).

Comment: Alright @AlejandroCamposPalacios did it work for you?

Comment: I just needed add `<include layout="@layout/app_toolbar"` to make it work. Now it works @the_underrated